# On YouTube, how can I see the top n video over 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, etc?

Tags: youtube

I used to be able to choose top videos [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com), where you would pick a category (sports, etc) and then you could choose from:

- 1 day
- 1 week
- 1 month
- All time

I can't seem to find this feature anymore.  Does it still exist and if so, how I do a see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this might be just what you want:

http://www.youtube.com/charts/videos_views?t=a

You can choose day, week, month from the top left buttons.